# Массив строки

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает эта программа.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char stroka[50];
    int i, n;
    do {
        cin >> stroka;
        for (n = 0; stroka[n] != '0'; n++);
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            cout << stroka[i];
        }

        cout << endl;
    } while (1);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Считывается строка, размером в 50 символов (51 - перенос строки).
2. В цикле `do->while` выводится реверс считанной строки.
3. Делается такая процедура очень много раз, бесконечно.

---

Можно оптимизировать код так, чтобы последние 2 строчки не были "воздухом":

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char stroka[50];
    int i, n;
    do {
        cin >> stroka;
        for (n = 0; stroka[n] != '0'; n++);
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            cout << stroka[i];
        }

        cout << endl;
    } while (stroka[0,1,2]!='0');  // != "000"

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
cin >> stroka;
```

Слово считывается с клавиатуры в массив

```
for (n=0; stroka[n]!='\0'; n++);
```

Определяется длина считанного слова

```
for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--) { 
  cout << stroka[i]; }
```

Выводятся символы этого слова в обратном порядке: от последнего до первого.

И все в бесконечном цикле.

Что еще непонятно?

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы. Немного прояснилась ситуация.

Я только вот все еще не могу понять, как этот цикл определяет длину введенного слова(или цифры) и выводит ее/его в обратном порядке, если я ввожу все слово целиком.

Я пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в массивах, но я понимаю массивы следующим образом: в массиве может храниться несколько строк(цифр), но вводятся они по-отдельности. Например - int fak[8] = {1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040}; А здесь получается, что мы вводим число или строку целиком, а программа каким-то образом реверсирует ее/его.

Comment: А нужно знать о негласном соглашении - строки заканчиваются нулем.
Вот тот цикл и ищет этот ноль. Понятное дело, если ввести строку более 50 символов, то может быть маленькое (а может и большое) ЧП.

Comment: Только это соглашение не негласное, а строго прописанное в стандарте.

Comment: Ребята, еще раз большое спасибо. Вы мне помогли понять работу цикла и массива в сто раз быстрее и лучше, чем пытался это сделать мой лектор за все время полуторачасовой лекции.

Также перед задачей вопроса мне следовало бы прочитать про сам массив строки по-внимательней. Вот ссылка, если кому понадобится. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<iostream>
// подключаем "стандарное простространство имен"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char stroka[ 50];
    int i, n;

    do {
        // ввод строки.
        cin >> stroka;
        // это просто подсчет длины строки.
        for (n = 0; stroka[n] != '\0'; n++) ;
        // а теперь, пробегая циклом от конца к началу строки
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // выводим посимвольно ее
            cout << stroka[i];
        }
        // и конечно же добавим переход на новую строку.
        cout << endl;
        // циклимся
    } while (1);
    // теперь типа ждем нажатия enter, но смысла особого нет.
    // Код сюда не добежит
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В целом, это код на С, написанный с небольшой примесью с++ и парочкой велосипедов.